# Relaunching a cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, process

I have an application that checks its command line parameters and stores values in persistent stores.  One of those is a password that I don't want sticking around for people to see with 'ps' and friends.  The approach I'm currently looking at is to, after I've stored the values I need, relaunch the process without the command line parameters.  My naive approach is this, where args[0] is the path to the application:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:[args objectAtIndex:0]];
[task launch];
[task release];
[NSApp terminate:nil];
```

The child is run.  However, when my app is terminated the child doesn't seem to orphan but gets stuck.  Am I just way off on this one?

More info:  So it seems that when I call [NSApp terminate:nil] the NSTask that was launched gets stuck, but if I just exit() then it works fine.  However, I'm concerned that things that are open (keychain, plist, etc.) will be in a bad state if I do that.

And note that lots of example code out there is about some watchdog-like process that restarts a separate process when needed.  I'm trying to restart the current process that's already running from within that same process.

Comment: If you're using Sparkle in your project you can use their relaunch code rather than writing your own. I posted about it on my blog last month. http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2010/06/03/restart-your-cocoa-application-using-sparkle/

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm not using sparkle but that blog post opened my eyes to the possibility.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are plenty of examples on the web, but [this one](http://snipplr.com/view/3923/relaunch-an-application/) (also below) looks like it has all the code you need.  There are [more detailed explanations](https://web.archive.org/web/20110904035851/http://iloveco.de/relaunching-your-application/) out there, as well.

```
// gcc -Wall -arch i386 -arch ppc -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -Os -framework AppKit -o relaunch relaunch.m
 
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
 
@interface TerminationListener : NSObject
{
    const char *executablePath;
    pid_t parentProcessId;
}
 
- (void) relaunch;
 
@end
 
@implementation TerminationListener
 
- (id) initWithExecutablePath:(const char *)execPath parentProcessId:(pid_t)ppid
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        executablePath = execPath;
        parentProcessId = ppid;
 
        // This adds the input source required by the run loop
        [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTerminate:) name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification object:nil];
        if (getppid() == 1) {
            // ppid is launchd (1) => parent terminated already
            [self relaunch];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
 
- (void) applicationDidTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (parentProcessId == [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"] intValue]) {
        // parent just terminated
        [self relaunch];
    }
}
 
- (void) relaunch
{
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:executablePath]];
    exit(0);
}
 
@end
 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) return EXIT_FAILURE;
 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 
    [[[TerminationListener alloc] initWithExecutablePath:argv[1] parentProcessId:atoi(argv[2])] autorelease];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];
 
    [pool release];
 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I've seen that one, but it looks like it's trying to run a specific method whereas I only want to relaunch the whole application.  I probably misunderstood; I'll check it again.

Comment: Ok, so the only problem here now is that I'm trying to launch a new copy of the same process I'm already in.  So if I use NSWorkspace to launch the process it sees that what I want to launch is already running and doesn't launch a new one.  I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: Ok, I get it.  The example you linked to is a separate executable that you run from somewhere else and have it restart your original process.

Comment: I'm using `system("open -n ...")` in one of my apps. Mostly because I'm very unfamiliar with Objective-C. Would that be considered extremely poor practice?

Answer (score 3):

I know its a bit late to answer but this answer may help others. Here is a cool trick that can help you.

By using the terminal command, just open your application as a **new instance** and **terminate** the current instance.

This is how it is done:

```
....        
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

        NSString* cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"open -n %@", path];

        [self runCommand:cmd];

        exit(0);
    }

    /// temrinal function

    -(NSString*)runCommand:(NSString*)commandToRun;
    {
        NSTask *task;
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

        NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"-c" ,
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                              nil];
        NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
        [task setArguments: arguments];

        NSPipe *pipe;
        pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

        NSFileHandle *file;
        file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

        [task launch];

        NSData *data;
        data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

        NSString *output;
        output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an external process that launches yours when it terminates. Then terminate. Launching Cocoa programs with NSTask doesn't work quite right.

Comment: Yes, I finally got that after reading that example linked above one more time.  Since that answer was posted first they get the green check, but you confirmed my suspicions so I had to at least vote you up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still wants to use NSTask to relaunch,I found one possible way: Please DO NOT set NSPipe of the NSTask,because the NSTask will terminate the app itself,once the app terminated,the NSTask that started might get stuck there.

At least for me,after I removed the NSPipe settings,my app relaunch successfully.
The following is what I do:
1. Write a command line tool which has 3 parameters: app bundle id,app full path,please note that in this command line you need to terminate the app and wait for a while to make sure it is really terminated before launch the new one,I keep checking app.isTerminated and sleep(1) if it's not terminated.

2. Launch the Command line tool in app using NSTask,and set the parameters accorddingly,Don't use NSPipe,simply create NSTask and launch
3. The app relaunches now